# Boxes side by side?

Tags: html

I can't figure out how to put the two div boxes side by side.

The second box appears lower and in the middle. It should be in the middle, next to the first box. Can anyone figure out what I've done wrong?

```
<link href="http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/9832134.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="clearfix" id="resultcontainer" style="position: relative;">
    <center>
        <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
            <div class="result9832134">
                <div class="content pie">
                    <div class="boxtitle">
                        <div class="boxtitleinner">
                            <p style="text-align: center;">
                                <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #000000;">NYHEDER</span></span></span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxtext">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            <p style="text-align: left;">
                                <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;">N&aelig;ste kursusstart den 07/10 i Projektstyring i praksis &amp; PRINCE2&reg; Foundation cerificering.</span></p>
                            <p style="text-align: left;">
                                <span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</span></p>
                            <p style="text-align: left;">
                                <span style="font-size: 32px; color: #ffffff;"><a href="http://www.2b1group.dk/index2.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=126&amp;Itemid=91&amp;lang=da" style="color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Tilmelding her</span></a></span></p>
                            <p>
                                <span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</div>


<link href="http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/9832234.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div :="" border="" left="" position="" top="">
    <div class="clearfix" id="resultcontainer" style="position: relative;">
        <center>
            <div style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
                <div class="result9832234">
                    <div class="content pie">
                        <div class="boxtitle">
                            <div class="boxtitleinner">
                                <p style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: #000000;">PRAKTISK INFO</span></span></span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="boxtext">
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="http://www.2b1group.dk/kontakt.html" style="color: font-size: 24px; #ffffff;" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;">Find os her</span></a></span></p>
                                <p>
                                    &nbsp;</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;">Tlf: +45 1234 5678</span></p>
                                <p>
                                    &nbsp;</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span style="font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff;">Email: </span><span style="font-size: 24px;"><a href="mailto: bla@bla.dk" target="_blank">bla@bla.dk</a></span></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--[if lt IE 10]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://static1.grsites.com/user/generate/items/ie_compat.js"></script><![endif]-->        </center>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" id="resultcontainer" style="padding: 50px 0;">
    <center>
        &nbsp;</center>
    <div class="clearfix" id="resultcontainer" style="padding: 50px 0;">
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which two DIV boxes? What CSS are you currently using? Also the `link` element can only appear in the `head` section, you seem to be using it in the `body`?

Comment: Also, what is the colon in `<div :="" `?

Comment: please explain more, so we can help you.

Comment: Inline CSS is very bad practice, if I could downvote those who advised it, I would. Also, <center> is a deprecated element and should be done using CSS. So in answer to your question 'Can anyone figure out what I've done wrong?' Yes, a lot, but it's up to you to figure out why it's wrong otherwise you'll never learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/uBusa/

```
#resultcontainer{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}​
```

Comment: Isn't `display:inline-block;` superfluous? floated elements are taken out of the flow of the page and implicitly displayed as blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Sadly I can't vote your answer up since I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a style of `float: left;` on both of the divs. You could also put a height and width on them if you needed them to be the same size.

If you float them both you also might need to put a third div under them to clear the float

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: There are better ways to clear floated DIVs, rather than using additional markup - you can clear the DIVs in CSS by including `overflow:hidden` on the container.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Sadly I can't vote your answer up since I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

You must add float:left on del divs

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: left;float:left;">

<div :="" border="" left="" position="" top="" style="float:left;>
```

Comment: floating an element that has `width:100%` is not going to help.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Sadly I can't vote your answer up since I don't have enough reputation yet.